# Grails - Message bundles (i18n) broken for war build only

Tags: grails, internationalization, war, grails-3.3, message-bundle

After upgrading from **2.5.5** to **3.1.1**, when I build my application as an executable war (or deploy to tomcat container), messages cannot be resolved from message.properties or any i18n properties files.

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'timeZoneId' for locale 'en_US'.
```

When run in IntelliJ, it all works fine.

In terms of configuration, I’ve tried to make my build as close to the “out of box” Grails app as possible.

I’m wondering if anyone could provide a hint or suggestion as an avenue of investigation I could travel down as I’m just about out of ideas. Happy to add configuration detail as requested.

I'm using a multi-module build with a plugin as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that maybe you have done some modification on your Grails project (2.5.5) that cant be support on the newest grails 3.3.0.

I would suggest you to check 3.3.0 documentation on how to customise your msg.

You can refer to https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/validation.html. There is an example of how to modify your own label or msg.

> In the case of the blank constraint this would be user.login.blank so you would need a message such as the following in your grails-app/i18n/messages.properties file:
>
> user.login.blank=Your login name must be specified!

Hope it helps. Cheers